# Google sheets query does not return results including parentheses ()

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet [(link)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13QMbgGct_xZOVXmM6J1RZNM4cPQVKENaHslK5FRSd5k) where I'm running a trivial query to find values based on a cell with piped values.

```
=QUERY(A1:A8;"select A where A matches '"&C2&"'";-1)
```

The piped values are

```
word 1|word (1)
```

The range is

```
Entries
word (1)
word (2)
word (2)
word (1)
word 1
word 2
word 1
```

For some reason, I don't get any results which include parentheses `()`.

It works well with the following query

```
=QUERY(A1:A8;"select A where A = 'word (1)'";-1)
```

Are there any **limitations with using parentheses `()`** with the matches function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to **escape parenthesis** for the query to work
This means that the correct syntax for your `C2` cell is

```
word 1|word \(1\)
```

You can even use

```
="word 1|word \(1\)"
```

Your formula will still be

```
=QUERY(A1:A8;"select A where A matches '"&C2&"'";-1)
```

[image]